# What Data Structure should I use for this particular case?

Tags: swift, data-structures

I have a dictionary, something like this

```
var dict = [String : [String]]()
```

The functionality I want to achieve is that, I have a hashtable which I can quick get the list of data from.

In my code, I use a dictionary and an array.

I am not very good with algorithem and data structure, so I am wondering if there is any better data structure that is suitable for something like this?

Comment: I honestly don't understand what is the problem, you want to achieve what? What is wrong with [String : [String]] ?

Comment: You should compare the complexity between the data structure you used and other available data structures/algorithms  .

Answer (score 0):

**Use:**

```
var dict = [String : [String]]()
```

Swift already has built in search algorithms that allow you you to retrieve data inside of your dictionary with simple subscript syntax like so

```
dict["element"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You will use it in this way -

Declaration:

`var dict: [String: [String]] = [:]`

Initialise:

`dict["element"] = myArray`